# Show/hide button in thickbox depending on from which page it is opened

Tags: thickbox

I use the [Taxonomy Images plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/) and it generates a button in the thickbox for associating an image with a term ([see screenshot](http://moargh.de/daten/thickbox.png)). Due to the fact that I can only associate terms with images in a thickbox that is opened from edit-tags.php pages, is it possible to remove the button from all other thickboxes?

Here’s the function that creates the button:

```
/**
 * Modal Button.
 *
 * Create a button in the modal media window to associate the current image to the term.
 *
 * @param     array     Multidimensional array representing the images form.
 * @param     stdClass  WordPress post object.
 * @return    array     The image's form array with added button if modal window was accessed by this script.
 *
 * @access    private
 * @since     2010-10-28
 * @alter     0.7
 */

function taxonomy_image_plugin_modal_button( $fields, $post ) {
    if ( isset( $fields['image-size'] ) && isset( $post->ID ) ) {
        $image_id = (int) $post->ID;

        $o = '<div class="taxonomy-image-modal-control" id="' . esc_attr( 'taxonomy-image-modal-control-' . $image_id ) . '">';

        $o.= '<span class="button create-association">' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Associate with %1$s', 'taxonomy-images' ), '<span class="term-name">' . esc_html__( 'this term', 'taxonomy-images' ) . '</span>' ) . '</span>';

        $o.= '<span class="remove-association">' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Remove association with %1$s', 'taxonomy-images' ), '<span class="term-name">' . esc_html__( 'this term', 'taxonomy-images' ) . '</span>' ) . '</span>';

        $o.= '<input class="taxonomy-image-button-image-id" name="' . esc_attr( 'taxonomy-image-button-image-id-' . $image_id ) . '" type="hidden" value="' . esc_attr( $image_id ) . '" />';

        $o.= '<input class="taxonomy-image-button-nonce-create" name="' . esc_attr( 'taxonomy-image-button-nonce-create-' . $image_id ) . '" type="hidden" value="' . esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'taxonomy-image-plugin-create-association' ) ) . '" />';

        $o.= '<input class="taxonomy-image-button-nonce-remove" name="' . esc_attr( 'taxonomy-image-button-nonce-remove-' . $image_id ) . '" type="hidden" value="' . esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'taxonomy-image-plugin-remove-association' ) ) . '" />';

        $o.= '</div>';

        $fields['image-size']['extra_rows']['taxonomy-image-plugin-button']['html'] = $o;
    }
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'taxonomy_image_plugin_modal_button', 20, 2 );
```